# Advanced protection on Google spreadsheet for multi-user

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a sheet that carries information of five people. I want them to input on the sheet by themselves. but once they give input they will not be able to edit it. Don't want to use google forms. is it possible? or separate sheet logs the edit history of that particular sheet.

Comment: This doesn't look as a programming question. Perhaps you should post your question on [webapps.se] instead of [so].

Answer (score 0):

You can check version history which will show all the changes by all the users.

[image]